# Check words from a list as uppercase lowercase and mixed

Tags: python, django

i want to check if a user wants to use a forbidden username at sign up, sadly this currently only works with lowercase. How can i make this work for upper,lower,mixed scenarios?

```
def forbidden_usernames(value):
    words = ["manager", "admin", "member", "staff", "support", "root"]
    if any(word in value for word in words):
        raise ValidationError(
            "Please don't use usernames like: admin, root, support etc.",
            code="invalid_username",
        )
```

Comment: Convert `value` to lower case for your checks.

Comment: assuming value is a string. Just do `value.lower()`

Comment: Merci that helped :D
Problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If value is a string, then just call its `lower` method.

```py
def forbidden_usernames(value):
    words = ["manager", "admin", "member", "staff", "support", "root"]
    if any(word in value.lower() for word in words):
        raise ValidationError(
            "Please don't use usernames like: admin, root, support etc.",
            code="invalid_username",
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
if any(word in value.lower() for word in words):
```